# Moment estimator $\hat{\theta}$ of $\mathrm{Beta}(\theta,1)$ and bias of $\hat{\theta}$

Tags: statistics, estimation, expected-value, parameter-estimation

I'm trying to find the moment estimator for the density function $$f(y)=\theta y^{\theta-1}$$ and check whether this is biased.

I know this is a $Beta(\theta,1)$ distribution and it looks like I only need to find the first moment in order to find the estimator.

For $Y\sim \mathrm{Beta}(\theta,1)\implies\bar{Y}=\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$

$$\theta\bar{Y}+\bar{Y}=\theta \implies \hat{\theta}=\frac{\bar{Y}}{1-\bar{Y}}$$

I'm pretty sure I've got that correct but I have no idea how to check whether this is biased or not. Finding the convolution isn't panning out too well and I can't seem to figure out a way to manipulate the expression in $\bar{Y}$ to give me anything to work with.

Any pointers towards answering this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh whoops, forgot I'd already made the original post

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$ is a non-linear function so you would expect your estimator to be biased.  It is a strictly convex function on $[0,1)$ so you would expect your estimator to be biased upwards

Comment: That does make sense but I guess it wouldn't hurt to find the bias of the estimator in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $\mathsf{Beta}(\theta,1)$, we have $E(\overline X)=\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}$, the population mean.

Let $g(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$ be a function on $(0,1)$, so that $g''>0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

That is, as @Henry says, $g$ is convex.

By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality),

$$E( g(\overline X))>g (E(\overline X))$$

Or, $$E\left[\frac{\overline X}{1-\overline X}\right]>\frac{E(\overline X)}{1-E(\overline X)}=\theta$$

Note that equality does not hold in the inequality above as $g$ is not a constant or an affine function.

Finding the actual value of $E\left[\frac{\overline X}{1-\overline X}\right]$ is non-trivial as the sampling distribution of $\overline X$ is not a standard one. So I would not worry about the exact bias of the estimator here.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense. I didn't think to use Jensen's inequality. I couldn't think of any way of finding the actual value of $E\left[\frac{\bar{X}}{1-\bar{X}}\right]$ without ending up with something that was ridiculously complicated or just didn't give a nice answer. Thanks